# Gravitational waves in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, universe, dark-energy, gravitational-waves

1. After reading some concepts of general relativity,is it true that the universe communicate with its different constituents (stars, galaxies, etc...) via gravitational wave? If so, how is that? Do these waves function as energy transmitted all over the universe?
2. Is it our dark energy?

Comment: The universe is not one or more sentient beings (at least not in mainstream science), and thus it does not "communicate".

Comment: @HDE226868 The universe does communicate with itself in the same way that the molecules in a piece of steel communicate to hold its rigidity.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational waves are not dark energy. Dark energy is closer to a fluid that is created when space expands and is destroyed when space is destroyed. That a fluid can do that requires a particular balance between energy and pressure one that is not normally achievable but if there were a fluid like that it would just keep filling everything.

Classical gravitational waves are like a friction. When you shake charges around they might create outgoing radio waves (that's how radio stations work) and thus the charges had to be pushed harder than you expected to create that radio wave in addition to giving the charge some speed (so it costs money to power hour radio station). When things move around gravitationally they can create gravitational waves and then they slow down compared to what would have done otherwise. Its more complicated than that. For instance you could have a spherical shell that moved radially in and out and it actually wouldn't radiate. So you have to move in a wave where the shape of your .option lines up properly with the shape that the wave makes.

But this is unrelated to gravitons or quantum mechanics. And it is also unrelated to how planets orbit stars or how the noon orbits the earth and is also unrelated to how and why an apple falla from a tree.  All of those things happen for a totally different reason.

The reason is that spacetime is curved and it has natural ways it can curve. Ways it can curve all on its own out in empty space.  Some of those natural ways have a type that can be given a numerical label.  For instance you could have a type $M$ solution and a type $m$ solution. And each is perfectly fine on its own. But if $M>m$ and you have $M-m$ amount of mass or $(M-m)c^2$ of energy and you place it on a spherical shell of surface area $4\pi R^2$ then you can sew those two solution together so that you have a type $M$ solution on the outside and a type $m$ solution on the inside of that spherical shell. And that is what mass does. It allows two natural curvatures to meet up. If that mass then contracted then the $M$ type that was in the outside would continue into the new region and the old $m$ type solution won't be there anymore. And the type $M$ has stronger curvature closer in (and is stronger closer in than the type $m$ curvature was). So the curvature increases. That is how spacetime becomes curved. When the things that made the sun contracted they left behind a curved spacetime that was more curved. And that's the spacetime the earth reacts to and that is why the earth orbits the sun. And a similar process that happened when the earth formed it contracted from a more spread out arrangement of rocky matter so it left the spacetime outside it more curved and that's why apples fall.

Comment: _Was it can curve all on its own out in empty space._ Would you mind just clarifying that line, top of your last paragraph. Thanks

Comment: @AcidJazz Sorry, should have been "Ways it can curve" I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

There are many different forces which can affect various types of particles: electromagnetism, gravitation, weak force and strong force. These forces act in different ways to change the state of other particles which are sensitive to that particular force and transfer information from one part of the system to another via these interactions.

Electromagnetism, for example, sends information in the form of photons. When two positively charged particles are brought close together, they are repelled from one another via the electromagnetic force. Quantum mechanically, these particles are exchanging virtual photons at the speed of light. These virtual photons exist only to transmit the electromagnetic force and this communication, on average, results in the macroscopic force between objects we are capable of observing.

The other quantum forces (weak and strong) operate on similar principles, but the particles they use for communication are different (I unfortunately have never taken a course in QCD, so I have to be a bit hazy here).

Gravity is a bit different in that it really does not play well with quantum theory, so we won't go too far down that rabbit hole. When you look at standard general relativity though, you find that there are two degrees of freedom not related to your choice of coordinates which are what we call gravitational waves (In weak field quantizations of GR I believe these become the graviton). When you look at two massive objects orbiting each other in GR, you find that their orbits decay and that angular momentum and energy are being given off in the form of gravitational radiation. This radiation stretches and squeezes space around the wave in a really interesting way, but it is by far **not** the dominant way that general relativity affects objects and does not account for the orbits of planets or anything of that sort.

As Timaeus said, dark energy is like a fluid that is created when space is created. But how can space be created and what does that mean? Well picture a balloon and draw two dots on it. When you blow up the balloon, the two dots appear to drift further and further apart **even though neither point is moving compared to the local area around it**. The space between the points is simply expanding. Something analogous happened in the early universe (and is still going on today) where the distance between distant objects is getting further and further. Since none of these objects are actually racing away from each other (remember its the distance between them that is getting bigger), we need something to drive the expansion. This something turns out to be dark energy. You can think of it as the energy associated with taking up space and it creates a positive pressure that pushes space apart making more and more space (its completely unrelated to gravitational radiation).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why would you say that virtual photons are exchanged at he speed of light? There is no requirement that a virtual particle be on shell hence it doesn't have to go at light speed. Plus exchanging particles is not really how interactions happen. So I see nothing to salvage from claiming this.

Comment: Space is created normally. A shell of matter collapses to form outside curvature & more volume is created of the new type of curvature above the surface than volume destroyed of the old type inside the shell. For example imagine a horizontal disk placed on a funnel (Schwarzschild on the outside Minkowski on the inside) then if you replace the disk with a smaller one the disk falls down that means extra space outside when the circumference got smaller. So creating space is a normal everyday thing it happens when objects fall deeper into a gravity well if you take the object's grav into account

Comment: He isn't going to understand a technical explanation and in a cosmological setting that doesn't happen. You are of course right about virtual photons being off shell, but the net effect is that information is transmitted at the speed of light and it is exactly via particle exchange that we get the coulomb force and magnetic field between dipoles.